# Python: How to store and read ini file with key having value containing = and semicolon

Tags: python, configuration-files, ini

I have an .ini file. Many keys in the file have values containing special characters like equalto(=), semicolon(;), comma(,). Sample .ini file:

```
[TestKey]
Key1=a=b=c
```

The key `Key1` value is `a=test;b=test`. The key value pair looks distorted. To resolve this, I enclosed the value in single quotes. The file structure looks fine but on  trying to read the value  of the key it gives `'a=test;b=test'` . The single quotes gets added as part of the key value. So the value is incorrect

Comment: [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) is in the Python standard library.

Comment: @aryamccarthy: I tried with configparser, but how to handle special characters like semicolon and =

Comment: _" I enclosed the value in single quotes_" is OK. Split the result with `a,b = result[1:-1].split(';')`